# Three way relation in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relation

Can someone tell me if I can do something like "three way relation", but one of three table would work as reference to another ?

Example tables:

```
articles, gallery, gallery_category
```

In this case I would like to fetch related gallery in article by gallery_category table.

I just have a simple system for adding articles, galleries and its category. While we are adding new article we can choose gallery that will be linked to this article and I have only connection with gallery_category table for articles, but then I would like to fetch proper gallery following this category <> article relation. Is it possible ?

For now I can check gallery category for added article:

```
$article->category
```

Here I would like to get something like this:

```
$article->category->gallery
```

For one article I link only one category, so it will be one ID.
Thanks for help.

Comment: What is your table schema for the 3 tables (just the keys/foreign keys is fine)

Answer (score 0):

You could read about Eloquent ORM Relations in Laravel documentation. Read about [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#eager-loading)